# Content Elements doesn't have a {count} variable

Tags: content-elements, count

I wanted to insert a related-articles block after the n-th content element using stash. But it seems Content Elements doesn't provide a `{count}` variable in the elements loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a `{ce_counter}` variable to the elements loop.

Open the `ft.content_elements.php` file and navigate to the `replace_tag` function.

Insert `$i_counter = 0;` just before the foreach `$data` loop.

In the loop, look for the `// Counter` section and add:

```
$i_counter++;
$tagdata_parsed = str_replace('{ce_counter}', $i_counter, $tagdata_parsed);
```

In the loop, look for the `// Parse varibles in conditions` sections and add `'ce_counter' => (int) $i_counter` as an extra array item.

Now you can use `{ce_counter}` as a variable in the loop.